# Changes in JSON file arent used in app - Flutter

Tags: json, debugging, flutter, assets

When I make changes to my JSON File and I reinstall the app on my Android device it is using a previous version of the JSON File sometimes.

Deinstall the app and clear all the data didnt resolve the issue.
Packages get & update in pubspec.yaml didnt help either.

Im loading the data with a FutureBuilder with

`future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/EN.json")`

as part of loading the json File.

expected: change the dummydata from the jsonfile from dummyTitle7 to July
and on next run of the app to see the title July

actual: still having dummyTitle7 as the title althoug the jsonfile has changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that your pubspec.yaml file reflects the change in assets and run

```
flutter packages get
```

After you update any of your assets

Comment: Ive done it already, but now Ive looked what is related to that, and I realized I didnt save the file before